# did Microsoft App Center support Baidu Push?

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

did Microsoft App Center support Baidu Push?

When I login to App Center, I only found that FCM and APNS supported.

if not at the moment, will it be in the roadmap?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. Don't forget too that product support is provided directly from within App Center. Just click the blue chat button in the lower-right corner of any page and you're connected to the product's dedicated support team.

You can read more about this at https://intercom.help/appcenter/getting-started/getting-help-with-app-center.